# Spring boot docker running on 8080 only?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I have deployed my spring boot application on docker but when I am trying to run it, it is only running on 8080 port not any other port i.e 3000 from logs I am able to deduce that it has something to do with internal tomcat listens to 8080 port. can anyone please tell me what is happening inside?

below are the logs when I am running on 8080

```
2021-02-14 05:53:36.156  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ebi.uk.EbiProjectJavaApplication     : Starting EbiProjectJavaApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_212 on 8a710deb6884 with PID 1 (/ebiProjectJava.jar started by root in /)
2021-02-14 05:53:36.160  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ebi.uk.EbiProjectJavaApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-14 05:53:37.426  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-14 05:53:37.663  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 224 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-02-14 05:53:38.750  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-02-14 05:53:38.770  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-14 05:53:38.771  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-02-14 05:53:38.902  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-14 05:53:38.903  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2621 ms
2021-02-14 05:53:39.139  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-02-14 05:53:39.648  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-02-14 05:53:39.732  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-02-14 05:53:39.817  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
2021-02-14 05:53:39.990  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-02-14 05:53:40.149  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-02-14 05:53:40.898  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-02-14 05:53:40.909  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-02-14 05:53:41.299  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-02-14 05:53:41.595  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-14 05:53:42.091  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7b94089b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@ee86bcb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1f010bf0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@bcef303, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@33308786, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7f132176, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6ed3f258, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7ca20101, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@10cf09e8, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19b93fa8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@71812481]
2021-02-14 05:53:42.410  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-02-14 05:53:42.424  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ebi.uk.EbiProjectJavaApplication     : Started EbiProjectJavaApplication in 6.864 seconds (JVM running for 7.751)
2021-02-14 05:54:13.163  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-02-14 05:54:13.164  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-02-14 05:54:13.167  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
```

below are the logs when I am trying to run on 3000

```
2021-02-14 05:50:58.993  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ebi.uk.EbiProjectJavaApplication     : Starting EbiProjectJavaApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_212 on b0f62c63fde2 with PID 1 (/ebiProjectJava.jar started by root in /)
2021-02-14 05:50:58.997  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ebi.uk.EbiProjectJavaApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-14 05:51:00.304  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-14 05:51:00.566  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 243 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-02-14 05:51:01.714  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-02-14 05:51:01.734  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-14 05:51:01.734  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-02-14 05:51:01.816  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-14 05:51:01.817  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2706 ms
2021-02-14 05:51:02.060  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-02-14 05:51:02.534  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-02-14 05:51:02.632  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-02-14 05:51:02.723  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
2021-02-14 05:51:02.909  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-02-14 05:51:03.163  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-02-14 05:51:04.045  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-02-14 05:51:04.055  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-02-14 05:51:04.480  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-02-14 05:51:04.799  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-14 05:51:05.330  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7ca20101, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@177bea38, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@40db2a24, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@41709512, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4f9a2c08, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6bca7e0d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@8ad6665, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@47f9738, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1921ad94, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7e6ef134, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@16ce702d]
2021-02-14 05:51:05.709  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-02-14 05:51:05.726  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.ebi.uk.EbiProjectJavaApplication     : Started EbiProjectJavaApplication in 7.436 seconds (JVM running for 8.28)
```

below is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
               <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring security test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

below is the command I am trying to run

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 ebiproject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing important concept here. `8080` is default port for spring boot application. But, in your docker network configuration you mapped `3000` -> `3000` which is wrong.

Instead, you should configure like below:
`docker run -p 3000:8080 ebiproject`

Comment: I did that from tutorials available,can you please explain the difference

Comment: Your containerized spring-boot application is running on top of docker container. And your docker container runs on docker host (maybe your machine). If you do not specify which ports are open, docker disables all access by default. Which means your app would be serving on container's 8080 port. But, again, since you did not expose container's 8080 port it will be unreachable. `-p 3000:8080` enables you to map your docker host's 3000 port to your container's (where spring-boot app runs) 8080 port.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing server port configuration in your application.{yml or properties}. 8080 is default port for spring boot application.
Thus by default this property is set for you automatically `server.port=8080`
If you are oblige to use port 3000, you can add this is your properties file
`server.port=3000`